# Spring for Android put. Cannot get response code

Tags: java, android, spring

I'm using Spring for Android and while using PUT request I cannot get response. Is there any way to get this working? I really love spring for android, but I don't know hgow to get it

http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e146

These are the methods I'm talking about:

```
 public void put(String url, Object request, Object... urlVariables) throws RestClientException;

 public void put(String url, Object request, Map<String, ?> urlVariables) throws RestClientException;

 public void put(String url, Object request, Map<String, ?> urlVariables) throws RestClientException;
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about showing the code of yours where you actually use it?

Comment: public void put(String url, Object request, Object... urlVariables) throws RestClientException;

public void put(String url, Object request, Map<String, ?> urlVariables) throws RestClientException;

public void put(String url, Object request, Map<String, ?> urlVariables) throws RestClientException;

Comment: These are the three methods I'm talking about, no responses

Comment: Well I was able to click on the link and I saw the methods you talk about. What I don't see is the context. I don't see how you use them, where you use them and how you are looking for a response. So show us the context!